# OpenSource Email Client in android

Tags: android

I'm developing email client type of app in android to send files and messages .Is there any Open source email client available in android so that i will get idea of how to develop email client app?

Comment: Strawberry, what do you mean by Open source email client?
Do you want to send an email without using intents or without any user intervention?

Comment: More than **developing**, it seems to be **modifying an existing app**

Answer (score 1):

May be look at the native source code ? Or the K9 email client source code ?

K9: https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/

Native email src : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Take a look at K-9 https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/
I actually use this app on my phone.